# Configure SQL Server 2008 with Kie-WB

Tags: drools, jbpm, wildfly-8, kie-wb

I've downloaded wildfly 8.2.1 and installed kie-server,kie-wb 6.4 and sqljdbc4-2.0 to it.In wildfly I've configured new datasource also.

I can see tables created in my database..but when I am creating any workflow using kie-wb..task information is not saved in DB.

Using this link :- http://blog.athico.com/2015/10/installing-kie-server-and-workbench-on.html, when I try to change persistence.xml and repack kie-wb war. When doing so Kie-wb is not launching. Please help me out.

T[image]hanks

Comment: In server log Exception :-[org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller/server/wildfly-kieserver error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller/server/wildfly-kieserver response code 405

Comment: I am launching server using this :- standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller -Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=alpha2 -Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=password@1 -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.ds=java:jboss/datasources/UserDS -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

Comment: What is your intended outcome and where exactly did you get stuck? Because in your question and comments I can see three completely different problems and I am not really sure what you want to accomplish. Anyway, the exception in your first comment means that KIE Server is not able to connect to its controller in KIE Workbench. Read [this series of blog posts](http://mswiderski.blogspot.cz/2015/09/unified-kie-execution-server-part-1.html) to learn more about KIE Server and how it can be configured.